# What to repair? Not booting, grub not accessible, first hard disk not booting from different grub

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, grub, liveusb

I am unsure how to repair my computer.

First, I thought it would be about GRUB2, but I'm not sure anymore.

I can:

- access BIOS. Booting from Live USB works fine. (It's EFI)
- access the F12-menu, however it's called. Booting live-usb works fine. (I'm using a Ubuntu Live USB. Same configuration like the computer itself. I guess I used it to install it.)
- access the filesystem from Live USB section. My computer works with lvm.
- not access the grub-menu. I tried these keys: <kbd>space</kbd>, <kbd>shift</kbd>, <kbd>esc</kbd>, <kbd>c</kbd>, <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>esc</kbd>.
- access the grub-menu while booting from live-usb by using <kbd>shift</kbd>.
- decide for the very last entry in this menu: `Boot from first hard disk`
- not boot this successfully. I get this error message:

  ```
  Booting from local disk…
  Boot failed: press a key to retry…
  ```

So, what's broken? GRUB or the entirely system? What do I need to repair?

I'm using:

- LVM
- UEFI
- Ubuntu

Comment: As only grub seems disfunctional, use a live usb linux, chroot into your pre-installed system and redo the grub installation.

Comment: After you booted from the live usb, give it a check to the partitions you already have, eventually try to mount them and check what's inside (and [edit]  the question updating the info). It seems there are no booting files installed (or it is not possible to find them, that is the same for grub) . Was the system working in the past?

Comment: It was. I can access the files from original system by booting live usb

Answer (score 0):

To load in UEFI mode, or boot from GPT in any mode, at least one boot partition outside LVM is required for the GRUB2 startup image, but not for bootloader files, and not for kernel images (not `/boot`).

more info https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#BIOS_systems

Try use `lilo`. `lilo` can perfectly install on a disk with LVM; can `/boot` in LVM; does not require that any MBR be created on the disk and works fine on the same Ubuntu 16.04, i.e. the package is there and it is adequate.

The trouble is in the other. The development of `lilo` stopped at the end of 2015. Well, on the other hand, it knows all that it takes to load a modern system entirely on LVM.